# Obj-C method not being recognized in same class

Tags: objective-c

I have a class that has a method:

```
-(NSInteger) getCityCountForState:(NSString *)state CityArray:(NSMutableArray *)cityArray {
NSInteger count = 0;
City *city = [[City alloc] init];

for(city in cityArray)
{
    if (city.state == state)
    {
        count++;
    }
}

return count;
}
```

That method is called from elsewhere in the same class:

```
count = [getCityCountForState:state CityArray:appDelegate.cities];
```

This gives the error "'getCityCountForState' undeclared (first use in this function)"

I have also tried:

```
count = [self.getCityCountForState:state CityArray:appDelegate.cities];
```

This gives the error "request for member 'getCityCountForState' in something not a structure or union"

I'm obviously missing something obvious...but I can't figure out what it is.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
count = [self getCityCountForState:state CityArray:appDelegate.cities];
```

Usual Objective-C naming conventions would argue for renaming that method a little, but that should get the call working, at least.

Edit: Here's a good place to start reading: [Coding Guidelines for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001282-BCIGIJJF). Personally, I'd argue for calling it:

```
- (NSInteger)countCities:(NSArray*)cities forState:(NSString*)state;
```

Comment: Specifically, each part of a method name should start with a lowercase letter (unless it's an initialism like URL), so that selector should be `getCityCountForState:cityArray:`.

Comment: ...and the 'get' prefix generally shouldn't be used unless you're using indirect parameters & writing into them - eg -[NSData getBytes:&buffer]

Comment: Thank you very much.  I renamed my method to countCities like you suggested.  I like that name better anyway.
:)

Answer (score 5):

You should also remove the line

```
City *city = [[City alloc] init];
```

And put `City *` in the `for` statement

```
for (City *city in cityArray)
```

This will make it a little short and remove a memory leak

Comment: I am still learning about pointers and memory management. Thanks for that advice.  I took it.

Answer (score 4):

Sixten answered correctly, but i thought i'd point out that your code has a memory leak; you don't need the [[City alloc] init] since you are reading them out of the array and not creating new ones in your logic.

If you're new to obj-c and cocoa i recommend reading the [Memory Management Guide](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/index.html).

Answer (score 4):

Objective-C method call syntax is:

```
   [receiver message]
```

When you wrote:

```
[getCityCountForState:state CityArray:appDelegate.cities]
```

You attempted to send a `CityArray:appDelegate.cities` message to `getCityCountForState:state`.

You should review Objective-C syntax.  Read Apple's introduction to the language.

Answer (score 0):

Is `-getCityCountForState:CityArray:` declared in your header, too? The definition must preceed the usages if not.

Comment: it was declared in the header, yes.